# Count values separated by commas and don't put comma in the last value

Tags: php, html, sql

So I am selecting values from database and they are like

[image: this]

and I am displaying the values on the site like

[image: this]

but it is not counting how much values are selected and it is inserting one comma in the last value expecting one more value to come.

This is the php code:

```
<?php
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_t)): ?>
<?php echo $row2['tipo'] . ", ";?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: _“but it is not counting how much values are selected”_ - and who or what exactly did you expect to magically count stuff purely on its own volition …? If you want to count anything here, then you have to _implement_ that.

Comment: what I meant to say it's that I am still learning and I don't know how to do that I am very noob xD

Comment: If you are learning and don’t know how to do something - then you should start with your own research first of all, before you come here and ask. And your question should include what you found during your own research, and then describe what specific problems you have with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `group_concat()` in MySQL:

```
select group_concat(tipo) as tipos
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the values from the DB in an array and then call implode() to join the individual values using comma.

Answer (score 0):

Implode the values (you will need to check how implode works [Link here](http://php.net/implode)) with a comma (,)